# Calculating displacement for a circular disc

Tags: image-processing, image

I have to calculate the difference in diameter of two concentric circles. The image is obtained from an experiment and the data looks like this.[image]

The length required is the value of l as marked in this figure.[image]

For the calculation, it is required to calculate the value of l at each point and then calculate the average l over the entire 2*Pi angle. This averaging is necessary for the calculation.
To calculate the average value of l averaged over the entire 2*Pi angle, I have first cleared the image and then obtained the binarized image as shown.[image]

However, I cannot calculate the value of the length l. Since I am new to Mathematica help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

The key idea to make this simpler is to apply a polar transform:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6oab.gif"];

center = 0.5 ImageDimensions[img];
maxR = 200;
polarToCart = center + {Cos[#[[1]]], Sin[#[[1]]]}*#[[2]] &;

polar = ImageTransformation[Binarize[img], polarToCart, {360, maxR}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2 \[Pi]}, {0, maxR}}, DataRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Now you can just process any column in this image to find the radii at different angles. The simplest thing that can work is to just count the white pixels:

```
ListLinePlot[Total /@ Transpose[ImageData[polar]]]
```

[image]

Depending on your data, you might want to count the longest run of white pixels instead (using [Split](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html)) or you might want to take a [distance transform](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceTransform.html) before applying the polar transform.

Comment: very beautiful solution!

Answer (score 5):

This is not an area I am familiar with but for fun here is approximation of the average thickness of annular region. This uses a lot version 10 functionality.

Importing the image:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BQEI.jpg"]
```

Using coordinate tools to calibrate image (`cal` is collected end points of ruler):

```
cal = {{1000.`, 9.333333333333314`}, {898.6666666666666`, 
    7.333333333333314`}};
cf[x_] := 25 x/EuclideanDistance @@ cal
```

Applying `EdgeDetect` to a cropped version of image:

[image]

Finding a circle that separate bounding circles:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot[PixelValuePositions[crop, 1]], 
  Graphics[Circle[{c1, c2}, r]]], {c1, 100, 300}, {c2, 100, 300}, {r, 
  50, 200}]
```

[image]

Fitting circles and determining different in radii:

```
reg = PixelValuePositions[crop, 1];
ir = ImplicitRegion[(x - 200)^2 + (y - 160)^2 < 103^2, {x, y}];
inner = Pick[reg, RegionMember[ir, #] & /@ reg, True];
outer = Pick[reg, RegionMember[ir, #] & /@ reg, False];
lfi = LinearModelFit[{#1, #2, #2^2 + #1^2} & @@@ inner, {x, y}, {x, 
    y}];
func[x_, y_] := lfi["BestFitParameters"].{1, x, y} - y^2 - x^2;
lfo = LinearModelFit[{#1, #2, #1^2 + #2^2} & @@@ outer, {x, y}, {x, 
    y}];
funco[x_, y_] := lfo["BestFitParameters"].{1, x, y} - y^2 - x^2;
cni = RegionCentroid[i = ImplicitRegion[func[x, y] == 0, {x, y}]]
cno = RegionCentroid[o = ImplicitRegion[funco[x, y] == 0, {x, y}]]
rado = RegionMeasure[o]/(2 Pi);
radi = RegionMeasure[i]/(2 Pi);
cf[rado - radi]
```

This yielded inner circle centre, outer circle centre and different in radi (in microns):

[image]

Looking at models:

```
lfi["ParameterTable"]
lfo["ParameterTable"]
```

[image]

and visualizing:

```
Show[Graphics[{Red, Thick, Dashed, Circle[cni, radi], Green, 
   Circle[cno, rado]}], ListPlot[{inner, outer}], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

The model assumes a circle. I look forward to better answers and corrections of likely misconceptions I have wrt image analysis.