# How to change image data (2D matrix) from cartesian to polar coordinate system?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, image-processing, image

I have a 2D matrix corresponding to the shown image in Cartesian coordinates. In image, the horizontal axis is x and vertical corresponds to y-axis. How to change this 2D matrix to polar coordinate system using mathematica ? [image]

Comment: A couple of related questions: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58495, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75462, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15960/counting-radial-ridges-on-an-image/15964, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27007/find-radii-of-concentric-circles-in-image/27013

Comment: @Niki Estner..These links discuss how to change image only. I have a 2D matrix in cartesian coordinate system...I want to change that data into polar...

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: @RGG: Turn the matrix into an image using `Image`, do a polar transform, then convert the result back into a matrix using `ImageData`. Some things in Mathematica are easier with `Image`s and some are easier with matrices, so converting between the two representations is pretty common in image processing in Mathematica.